# Как получить список групп, которым принадлежат территории?

Tags: c#

Мне необходимо получить группы территорий, которые принадлежат территориям.

Делается это так:

```
var territoryGroups = dbContext.Set<TerritoryGroup>()
     .Where( x => ids.Contains( x.ChildId ) )
     .ToList();
```

После этого, мне необходимо все это сгруппировать. Допустим, первая территория входит в первую группу, вторая территория во вторую группу, а третья входит в первую.
Ну и хочется получить что-то такое:

```
(key: [firstTerritory, thirdTerritory], value: firstGroup), (key: [secondTerritory], value: secondGroup)
```

Я решил сделать так:

```
var territoryGroups = dbContext.Set<TerritoryGroup>()
        .Where( x => ids.Contains( x.ChildId ) )
        .ToList();

var groupedTeritories = territoryGroups
         .GroupBy( x => x.ParentId)
         .Select( x => x)
         .ToDictionary(
         x => x.Select( x => new
         {
             x.ChildId
         } ).ToList(),
         x => x.Select( x => x.Parent )
               .Where( x => x.DeletionTime == null )
               .Distinct()
               .ToList()
);
```

На мой взгляд, это выглядит как-то плохо и некрасиво. Слишком много linq, что скажется на производительности
Помогите отрефакторить, пожалуйста

Модель:

```
public class TerritoryGroup
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Territory Parent { get; set; }

    public Guid ChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual Territory Child { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Для полноты картины покажите структуру сущности `TerritoryGroup`. На выходе вы хотите получить `Dictionary<List,List>`? И правда, некрасиво.

Comment: я дополнил. Да, на выходе, хотелось бы получить `Dictionary<List,List>`. Хотя.. можно и без словаря, думаю

Comment: А теперь добавьте `Territory`

Comment: `dbContext` - это что? Какая-то ORM? Какая именно? Укажите **точную** версию!

Comment: Список в качестве ключа? No way! Азы: нельзя использовать _мутируемый_ тип как ключ.

Comment: У сущности Группа напрашивается навигационное свойство-коллекция Территории.